# ORA-02256: el número de columnas de referencia debe coincidir con las columnas de referencias (este es el error que me devuelve)

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

```
create table Vaixell (

  Id_Vaixell varchar(20) not null,

  Cabines numeric not null,

  Restaurants numeric not null,

  N_persones numeric not null,

  PRIMARY KEY(Id_Vaixell)

);

create table Clients (

  Id_client varchar(20) not null,

  Id_billet varchar(20) not null,

  DNI varchar(20) not null,

  PRIMARY KEY(DNI,Id_billet,Id_client)

);

create table Cabina (

  Id_cabina varchar(20) not null,

  PRIMARY KEY (Id_cabina)

);

create table tipus_cabina (

 Id_tipus varchar(20) not null,

 Capacitat numeric not null,

 PRIMARY KEY (Id_tipus)

);

create table Botigues (

 Id_botiga varchar(20) not null,

 Nom_botiga char(10) not null,

 PRIMARY KEY(Id_botiga)

);

create table Tipus_botiga (

 tipo_botiga varchar(20) not null,

 PRIMARY KEY (tipo_botiga)

);

create table Rutes (

 Id_epoca varchar(20) not null,

 Id_ruta varchar(20) not null,

 PRIMARY KEY (Id_ruta)

);

create table Treballadors (

  DNI varchar(20) not null ,

  Id_treballador varchar(20) not null,

  Lloc_treball varchar(20) not null,

  Dia date not null,

  Hora TIMESTAMP not null,

  Nom char(10) not null,

  PRIMARY KEY(Id_treballador)

);

create table Restaurants(

 Id_restaurant varchar(20) not null,

 Id_menu varchar(20) not null,

 Id_reserva varchar(20) not null,

 Tipus varchar(20) not null,

 Preu numeric not null,

 PRIMARY KEY (Id_restaurant,Id_reserva,Id_menu)

);

create table Reserva (

  Id_reserva varchar(20) not null,

  Id_client varchar(20) not null,

  Id_billet varchar(20) not null,

  DNI varchar(20) not null,

  Id_ruta varchar(20) not null,

  Id_cabina varchar(20) not null,

  Preus int not null,

  Data_ date not null,

  PRIMARY KEY (Id_reserva,Id_billet,Id_ruta,Id_cabina,DNI,Id_client),

  CONSTRAINT clients_a_reserva_fk

    FOREIGN KEY (Id_billet,DNI,Id_client)

    references Clients (Id_billet,DNI,Id_client),

  CONSTRAINT rutes_a_reserva_fk

    FOREIGN KEY (Id_ruta)

    references Rutes (Id_ruta),

  CONSTRAINT cabina_a_reserva_fk

    FOREIGN KEY (Id_cabina)

    references Cabina (Id_cabina)

);

create table Excursions (

  Edat_minima numeric not null,

  Id_reserva varchar(20) not null,

  Descripcio varchar(100) not null,

  Opcional varchar(30) null,

  PRIMARY KEY(Edat_minima,Id_reserva),

  CONSTRAINT reserva_a_excursions_fk

    FOREIGN KEY (Id_reserva)

    references Reserva (Id_reserva)

);

create table Activitats (

  tipus_activitat varchar(20) not null,

  Id_reserva varchar(20) not null,

  PRIMARY KEY (tipus_activitat,Id_reserva),

   CONSTRAINT reserva_a_activitats_fk

    FOREIGN KEY (Id_reserva)

    references Reserva (Id_reserva)

);

create table Incidencies (

  Id_treballador varchar(20) not null,

  N_incidencia varchar(20) not null,

  Dia date not null,

  Hora TIMESTAMP not null,

  Comentari varchar(100) null,

  PRIMARY KEY(N_incidencia),

  CONSTRAINT Incidencies_a_treballador_fk

    FOREIGN KEY (Id_treballador)

    references Treballadors (Id_treballador)

);

create table Port_desti (

 N_port numeric(20) not null,

 Id_ruta varchar(20) not null,

 Ciutat_atracament varchar(20) not null,

 PRIMARY KEY (N_port,Id_ruta),

 CONSTRAINT ruta_a_port_fk

    FOREIGN KEY (Id_ruta)

    references Rutes (Id_ruta)

);

create table reserves_restaurant(

 Id_reserva varchar(20) not null,

 Id_menu varchar(20) not null,

 PRIMARY KEY (Id_reserva,Id_menu),

  CONSTRAINT Restaurants_a_reserves_fk

    FOREIGN KEY (Id_reserva,Id_menu)

    references Restaurants(Id_reserva,Id_menu)

);

create table client_a_reserva(

 Id_client varchar(20) not null,

 Id_restaurant varchar(20) not null,

 PRIMARY KEY (Id_client, Id_restaurant),

 CONSTRAINT clients_a_rerserva_fk

    FOREIGN KEY (Id_client)

    references Clients (Id_client),

 CONSTRAINT Restaurant_a_clients_fk

    FOREIGN KEY (Id_restaurant)

    references Restaurants (Id_restaurant)

);
```

Comment: Very poor editing, Very little details provided (only code). Question in question heading and it's not in english - voting to close.

Comment: I downvoted because [too much code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/), confused tagging ??`[sql-server]`??? , and finally **Por favor haga preguntas en inglés**

Comment: @miracle173 - cut'n'paste error :-\ Thanks for pinging me

Answer (score 0):

The columns in a foreign key must match the number and datatype of the columns in the referenced table's key.

You are expecting us to debug your several hundred lines of code which we are not going to do. What you need to do is stop running the whole script. One each statement individually. Then when one fails you know which one you need to fix.
`